# Convert data frame to polygon

Tags: polygon, raster, shapefile, r-sf, rgdal

I tried converting my data frame into polygon using the code from previous

post but I got an error message. Please I need assistance on how to fix this.

Thanks. Below is my code:

```
  County MEDIAN_V latitude longitude RACE DRAG AGIP AGIP2 AGIP3 

  Akpa  18.7    13.637  46.048  3521875 140.1290323 55  19  5
  Uopa  17.9    12.85   44.869  3980000 86.71929825 278 6   4

  Kaop  15.7    14.283  45.41   6623750 167.6746988 231 66  17

  Nguru 14.7    13.916  44.764  3642500 152.256705  87  15  11

  Nagima    20.2    14.7666636  43.249999   23545500    121.699 271 287 450

  Dagoja    17.2    16.7833302  45.5166646  2316000 135.5187713 114 374 194

  AlKoma    20.7    16.7999968  51.7333304  767000  83.38818565 NA  NA  NA

  Ikaka 18.1    15.46833146 43.5404978  5687500 99.86455331 18  29  11

  Maru  17.4    15.452  44.2173 10845625    90.98423127 679 424 159

  Nko   19.4    16.17   43.89   10693000    109.7594937 126 140 60
  Dfor  16.8    14.702  44.336  16587000    120.7656012 74  52  30

  Hydr  20.7    16.666664   49.499998   5468000 126.388535  2   5   NA

  lami  23  16.17   43.156  10432875    141.3487544 359 326 795

  Ntoka 16.9    13.9499962  44.1833326  21614750    134.3637902 153 84  2

  Lakoje    20.6    13.244  44.606  4050250 100.5965167 168 108 75

  Mbiri 14.6    15.4499982  45.333332   2386625 166.9104478 465 452 502

  Masi  18.2    14.633  43.6    4265250 117.16839   6   1   NA

  Sukara    20.6    16.94021    43.76393    6162750 66.72009029 974 928 1176

  Shakara   18.9    15.174  44.213  10721000    151.284264  585 979 574

  Bambam    18.8    14.5499978  46.83333    3017625 142.442623  101 84  134

  Erika 17.8    13.506  43.759  23565000    93.59459459 697 728 1034


  mydata %>%    
  group_by(County) %>%       
  summarise(geometry = st_sfc(st_cast(st_multipoint(cbind(longitude, 
  latitude)), 'POLYGON'))) %>% 
  st_sf()
```

After running the above I got an error message:

```
Error in ClosePol(x) : polygons require at least 4 points
```

Please can someone help me out with how to fix this.

Comment: You group by `County`. But every County exists only once in your dataframe, and has only one coordinate. How do you want to form polygons?

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea how it really works